# C++/CLI ref parameter overloading

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI value class(struct in C#) that for math.

As you know, math relevant structs are often using `ref` paramters for its methods for improve performance. And then, add a overloading that is non-`ref` version for convinience.

Such like this, in C#

```
public struct Vector
{
    public static Vector Add(Vector left, Vector right) => Add(ref left, ref right);
    public static Vector Add(ref Vector left, ref Vector right)
    {
        // Something.
    }
}
```

On the other hands, in C++/CLI, I had made `ref` versions such like below.

```
public value class Vector
{
public:
    static Vector Add(Vector% left, Vector% right)
    {
        // Something.
    }
}
```

It has not problem. That exposing `ref` parameters properly in C# project.

BTW, how about non-`ref` version.
I can declare its prototype, but I cannot call the `ref` version from that.

```
public value class Vector
{
public:
    static Vector Add(Vector left, Vector right)
    {
         return Add(left, right); // Compile error C2668.
    }
    static Vector Add(Vector% left, Vector% right)
    {
        // Something.
    }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: @AlexF You have miss one thing. The math operation needs a lot of deep copies. If using `class`, have to deep copy manually so often. It is really painful. Kind of Java.

Comment: @AlexF And I don't want needless garbages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your goal here?

If your goal is to have a API that can be called from C++/CLI, then ignoring the issue of how to implement the two versions, how would you call them from C++/CLI code? Since C++/CLI doesn't require an extra keyword when calling the ref version, you'll get error C2668 everywhere you try to use `Add`. In that case, I would implement the two versions with different names.

If your goal is to have an API that can be called from C#, then it might make sense to have these two methods with the same name, since C# can differentiate which one to call based on the `ref` keyword. In that case, I would implement `Add(Vector, Vector)` and `Add(Vector%, Vector%)` as *both* calling private method `AddImpl(Vector%, Vector%)`.

I haven't checked this with a compiler. Since the way you call the methods are so similar, you may get compiler errors even after you fix the implementations. Last I checked, an unmanaged C++ compiler won't even let you define an overload along the lines of `foo(int)` and `foo(int&)`, because they're called in exactly the same way. <sub><sup>(Though I might be mis-remembering that.)</sup></sub>

---

Now, all that said, let me say that this feels like a premature optimization to me. Consider implementing the 'call by value' versions only, and if your performance is acceptable, then there's no need for these extra hoops.

Also, you haven't shown your definition of what data is in your `Vector` type. If it's heavy-weight enough that you're considering call by reference to save time in copying the object, then perhaps the it should be changed to a reference type.

Comment: The `Vector` wrapping C++ function that is closed source. But my app using C#. Therefore C++/CLI needed. The `Vector` is just example. I have a struct that has 64bytes.

Comment: You means, it is the limitation of the language, right? It is no good but I'll add extension methods for it in C#. Thanks.